# Parent div of img tag doesn't get the size in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, height

The problem is a little bit complex, I spent hours with it until I found the reason of the bug.

I have a #container, with an img tag. The #container height is dynamic, I calculate it with JavaScript. The image has the following styles:

```
max-height:100%;
width:auto;
display:block;
```

The #container doesn't have any special property:

```
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
```

As you can see I would like to resize the image to fit in the #container.

When I did it on the local machine the #container didn't get the size of the img, it looks like it's 100%.

[image: This is the #container]

Same with the img:

[image: This is the img]

When I uploaded it to an online dev server I surprised because everything looked great.. until the next refresh when the browser loaded the image from the cache.

If the browser have to wait for the image everything works, but when the image loads immediately the problem occurs.

I load the javascript in the bottom, but I tried it in the header too. What is the solution?

**EDIT:**

```
function seteHeight() {
    var headerHeight = $('header').height();
    var footerHeight = $('footer').height();
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
    $('#container').css({
        'height': viewportHeight-footerHeight-headerHeight-40+'px',
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    setHeight();
});
```

EDIT2:

Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/pted5bs1/5/
Try with Chrome (Simple refresh, CTRL+R)

Comment: We need to see your code to help. Where is your JS?

Comment: I added the javascript code. The js is currently in the footer before the </body>, but I tried it on the top.

Comment: can you attach jsfiddle link. thanks

Comment: I edited the post with the jsfiddle link.

Comment: You moved the image? So if I wanted to explain it I have nothing to go on. Please put the image back so that if any users want explain they can.

Comment: I didn't. Lorempixel did. I updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether this is what you're looking for, and I don't know whether this is a hack.
All I did was change the CSS to this:

```
img 
{
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#container').css({
                'height': '200px',
            });
        });
```

to

```
$(window).load(function(){
        $('#container').css({
            'height': '200px',
        });
    });
```

and it will probably fix it.

Comment: Unfortunately the result is same when you load the image from cache/local.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/br97c05c/2/
I made one too and it seems ok.Either way if your #container has height :200px the image should be resized.